# Checking $\mathbb{K}_{U\times(a,b)}\ast\mathbb{K}_{[0,\infty)}\simeq \mathbb{K}_{U\times[a,\infty)}[-1]$ in derived category $D(X\times\mathbb{R})$

Tags: homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

Let $D(X\times\mathbb{R})$ be the derived category of sheaves of $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces on a smooth manifold $X\times\mathbb{R}$ where $\mathbb{K}$ is a ground field. Let $p_1:X\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow X\times\mathbb{R}$, $p_2:X\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $a:X\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow X\times\mathbb{R}$ be given by $p_1(x,t_1,t_2)=(x,t_1)$, $p_2(x,t_1,t_2)=t_2$ and $a(x,t_1,t_2)=(x,t_1+t_2)$. Then for $F\in D(X\times\mathbb{R})$ and $G\in D(\mathbb{R})$, we can define a convolution sheaf $F\ast G\in D(X\times\mathbb{R})$ given by $F\ast G=Ra_!(p_1^{-1}F\otimes p_2^{-1}G)$.

In this case, for an open subset $U\subset X$ and an open interval $(a,b)\subset\mathbb{R}$, I want to check the isomorphism $\mathbb{K}_{U\times(a,b)}\ast\mathbb{K}_{[0,\infty)}\simeq \mathbb{K}_{U\times[a,\infty)}[-1]$ in $D(X\times\mathbb{R})$. I checked that their stalks are isomorphic. So I need to check only that there is a natural morphism between them. But I don't know how to define this morphism.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use the adjunction since $Ra_!$ is a left adjoint.